# Perl and timezones

Tags: perl, time, timezone

I'm having a bit of trouble with timezones and Perl. I have a feed that comes from the (US) east coast; my server is in central time, and the end product needs to reflect eastern time. From the feed I get times like `HH:mm` (it's from a schedule and is the same for any day). So I convert this into epoch using `str2time`. Now when I send the schedule to the client (a JSON) I'm sending server time. The problem I'm running is that I don't really want to `my $time = time() + 3600` to add the hour from EST/EDT. My question is: can I add that hour in a different way?

Comment: You could investigate the Perl DateTime family of modules, and in particular the DateTime::TimeZone modules.  You'd have to characterize US/Eastern and US/Central appropriately, but you could then use these to convert the timestamps from Central to Eastern.

Comment: What *exactly* do you get back from the feed?  Is it just the time?  A date and time?  A date and time and offset?  Is the time "Eastern Time" which might be EST or EDT, or is it fixed to EST? Or perhaps it is fixed to UTC?  Please show an example.

Comment: @Matt Johnson is wondering if you actually have enough information to accurately convert the time to epoch time.

Comment: I assume you want the time back for US Central Time? Or is it possible your client is in another time zone?  I'm also not convinced that you have the right value for the epoch time to start with.  It would help if you showed some code.  You said that you pass it to [`str2time`](http://search.cpan.org/~rse/lcwa-1.0.0/lib/lwp/lib/HTTP/Date.pm#str2time($str_[,_$zone])), but didn't say with what parameters or what the input string exactly looks like.  If it really is just `HH:mm` without a date, then this whole exercise is pointless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use DateTime qw( );

say DateTime
       ->from_epoch(epoch => $epoch, time_zone => 'America/Chicago')
          ->strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S');
```

Comment: I think that's just going to return back what he is starting with, no?  Although the question isn't very clear about what he wants to send back.

Comment: @Matt Johnson, oops, got the direction of change wrong. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

This is the Q&D or one-off "solution":

```
my @tvs = localtime( time );
$tvs[2]++;
my $eastern_time = POSIX::strftime( $my_format, @tvs );
```

That's the gist of it anyway. There are probably more complex solutions out there.

Comment: That is assuming that Eastern and Central are always one hour apart.  In fact, since each time zone in the USA applies DST according to their own local time, there is [an hour in March](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/converted.html?iso=20130310T03&p1=179&p2=64) where they are two hours apart, and [an hour in November](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/converted.html?iso=20131103T01&p1=64&p2=179) where they are exactly the same.

Comment: In other words, you might as well do `+ 3600`

Comment: @ikegami: "My question is: can I add *that hour* in a different way?"